# I ain't able to open db in cordova-sqlite-storage for ionic 1

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic 1 and are having a lot of problems to create a database in sqlite storage. Could you help me?

I am using the plugin with the name above, 'cordova-sqlite-storage'
The problem is, when the code pass in the openDB command it stop in there and aren't able to proceed.

Follow my code:

js/sqlite.js

```
var sqlite = angular.module('sqlite', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);

sqlite.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "rollers.db", bgType: 1 });
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clientes (id integer primary key, razaoSocial varchar(40), nomeFantasia varchar(40), CNPJ text, Endereco text)");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instalacao (id integer primary key, idCliente int, DataInst datetime)");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS manutencao (id integer primary key, idCliente int, idInstalacao int, DataManut datetime)");
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS equipamento (id integer primary key, idInstalacao int, idManutencao int, TC int, Rolo varchar(40))");
    });
})

sqlite.factory('clientesFactory', function ($cordovaSQLite) {
    return {
        insert: function (firstname, lastname, avatar, message) {
            var query = "INSERT INTO clientes    (razaoSocial, nomeFantasia, CNPJ, Endereco) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
            var values = [firstname, lastname, avatar, message];

            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, values).then(
              function (res) {
                  console.log('INSERTED ID: ' + res.insertId);
              },
              function (err) {
                  console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
              }
            );
        },

        insertInstalacao: function (idCliente, DataInst) {
            var query = "INSERT INTO instalacao  (idCliente, DataInst) VALUES (?, ?);";
            var values = [idCliente, DataInst];

            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, values).then(
              function (res) {
                  console.log('INSERTED ID: ' + res.insertId);
              },
              function (err) {
                  console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
              }
            );
        },

        insertInstalacao: function (idCliente, idInstalacao, DataManut) {
            var query = "INSERT INTO manutencao  (idCliente, idInstalacao, DataManut) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
            var values = [idCliente, idInstalacao, DataManut];

            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, values).then(
              function (res) {
                  console.log('INSERTED ID: ' + res.insertId);
              },
              function (err) {
                  console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
              }
            );
        },

        insertInstalacao: function (idInstalacao, idManutencao, TC, Rolo) {
            var query = "INSERT INTO equipamento (idInstalacao, idManutencao, TC, Rolo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
            var values = [idInstalacao, idManutencao, TC, Rolo];

            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, values).then(
              function (res) {
                  console.log('INSERTED ID: ' + res.insertId);
              },
              function (err) {
                  console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
              }
            );
        },

        select: function (id) {
            var query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id=?";
            var values = [id];

            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, values).then(
              function (res) {
                  if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                      var first = res.rows.item(0);
                      console.log(res.rows.length + ' records, fist: ' + first.firstname + ' ' + first.lastname + ' - ' + first.avatar);
                  } else {
                      console.log('No records found');
                  }
              }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!--For users deploying their apps to Windows 8.1 or Android Gingerbread, platformOverrided.js
    will inject platform-specific code from the /merges folder -->
    <script src="js/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/sqlite.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

js/controller.js:

```
.controller('ClienteDetalheCtrl', function ($scope, clientesFactory) {
//.controller('ClienteDetalheCtrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.gravaCliente = function () {
        var primeiro_nome   = document.getElementById('TxtRazao').value;
        var segundo_nome    = document.getElementById('TxtFantasia').value;
        var avatar          = document.getElementById('TxtCNPJ').value;
        var mensagem        = document.getElementById('TxtEnd').value;
        clientesFactory.insert(primeiro_nome, segundo_nome, avatar, mensagem);
        clientesFactory.select(1);
        document.getElementById('TxtRazao').value = 'teste';
    }

    $scope.limpaCliente = function () {
        document.getElementById('TxtRazao').value = '';
        document.getElementById('TxtFantasia').value = '';
        document.getElementById('TxtCNPJ').value = '';
        document.getElementById('TxtEnd').value = '';
    }
})
```

app.js:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT = 30
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'sqlite'])
//angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (cordova.platformId === "ios" && window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
    // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
    // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
    // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
    $stateProvider

    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
      .state('tab', {
          url: '/tab',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
      })

    // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

    .state('tab.home', {
        url: '/dash',
        views: {
            'tab-home': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.manutencao', {
        url: '/manutencao',
        views: {
            'tab-manutencao': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/manutencao.html',
                controller: 'InstalacaoCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.instalacao', {
        url: '/instalacao',
        views: {
            'tab-instalacao': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/instalacao.html',
                controller: 'InstalacaoCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.instalacao-detalhe', {
        url: '/instalacao-detalhe',
        views: {
            'tab-instalacao-detalhe': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/instalacao-detalhe.html',
                controller: 'InstalacaoDetalheCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.cliente', {
        url: '/cliente',
        views: {
            'tab-cliente': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/cliente.html',
                controller: 'ClienteCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.cliente-detalhe', {
        url: '/cliente-detalhe',
        views: {
            'tab-cliente-detalhe': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/cliente-detalhe.html',
            controller: 'ClienteDetalheCtrl'
            }
        }
    });

    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

If you everyone, could help me i would stay really grateful.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in sqlite.js

```
sqlite.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "rollers.db", location: 'default' });
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clientes (id integer primary key, razaoSocial text, nomeFantasia text, CNPJ text, Endereco text)");
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instalacao (id integer primary key, idCliente integer, DataInst text)");
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS manutencao (id integer primary key, idCliente integer, idInstalacao integer, DataManut text)");
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS equipamento (id integer primary key, idInstalacao integer, idManutencao integer, TC integer, Rolo text)");
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used what you said and just change the place where my sqlite.js was being called and everything worked just well.         
  He was being called in the index.html after the cordova.js. When i put it in a place before the cordova.js everything worked well.